# How to make a zipped download with files that exist in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make some kind of user panel for my users - after they will update the info on the panel it will make a new row for them in the database with an original source code which i build but with the edited fields they made.

**Example:**

**UserName: [*_*__*_*___]**

**PageID: [*_*__*_*___]**

They fill it in and the when they press update it will automatically insert the data to a pre-made code to a new field in the table.

```
<?php
$username = ? (whats the best way to insert UserName textarea value in here?)
$pageid = ? (whats the best way to insert UserName textarea value in here?)
?>
```

**Now that was the first question: whats the best way to insert UserName textarea value in here?**

**The Second question is how to Auto Encrypt this on insert (I don't care about the way it will be encrypted, even if it will not be IonCube encrypted it will be fine)**

**And the last and the most important question is how to make an automatic function that when they will press "Update" will automatically make files from the SQL field and prompt them to download the zipped files with their files (I don't want to store any of those files on my server because they may interrupt one with the other cause there may be 100 users doing this action at the same time)**

Guys trust me i has been looking for this answers all over the net and didn't found a thing.. (I found EVERYTHING i need except this stuff).

Thanks for future assistance guys!

Best Regards, Rico S.

Comment: Please do not add pseudo-tags in your question title, like `[php, mysql]` -- we have *real* tags here!

Comment: Ok buddy. ill know that for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The best way to do it is by using some sort of formatting like 
Put you template like this
`$template = "whats the best way to insert %%UserName%% %%textarea%% value in here.";`

And then create an array with like

`$trans = array ("%%UserName%%" => $username, "%%textarea%% => $textarea);`

Then use php's `strtr` function to convert it

`$data_to_store = strtr($template, $trans);`

2) You can find a lot of encryption and decryption algorithms and php classes for doing that check out [PHP Classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?go_search=1&words=encryption).

3) You could try this. But i am not 100% sure if its works properly. 
Use PHP's [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) Directory
And then load the content's into  a string
then

```
<?php

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('php://stdout', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString('file.txt', $content_populated_from_db);
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
exit;

?>
```

I hope this works,  If it didn't try changing the flags of `ZipArchive::open`. And if it didn't work then also. In that case let me know, with you code and i might be able to help you. As of this point, i havn't tried it.